# Standard (no third-party) way to get numeric keypad working as arrow keys on macOS (Xcode? hidutil?)

Tags: macos, key-bindings

I always use numeric keypad as arrows, as I find it more convenient than using an separate arrow pad. Until recently I used a tool Karabiner Elements, but it stopped functionning at Big Sur.
Yes, The Karabiner developer is working on that issue, but it will be better to solve it without relying on a third-party tool.

It will be enough for me to either remap Xcode, or (which is preferred) to change key bindings in the system, using a tool like `hidutil`.

Xcode's `Preferences - Key Binding` has a section `Text - Section`. When I try to modify the binding for say `Move Down` by pressing `Down` arrow on numeric keypad it comes up as '2'. Now whereever I press '2', on keyboard or numeric keypad, it always works as `Move Down` which is certainly not what I am after.

About `hidutil`. I couldn't find a good manual or any example of keyboard mapping.

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had another look at this [article](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2450/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40017618-CH1-TNTAG8). Here is the answer:

```
hidutil property --set '{"UserKeyMapping":[{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x70000005A,"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x700000051},
{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x700000060,"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x700000052},
{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x70000005C,"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x700000050},
{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x70000005E,"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x70000004F},
{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x70000005F,"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x70000004A},
{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x700000061,"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x70000004B},
{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x700000059,"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x70000004D},
{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x70000005B,"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x70000004E},
{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x700000062,"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x700000049},
{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x700000063,"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x70000004C}]}'
```

Still can't fugure out, how to do (if possible) complex mapping with modifier keys (eg `Ctrl+PgUp` to `Home`), but that's another topic.